# How do I add a value to an empty MongoDB array?

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb

I've been trying to figure out what the problem is for the past hour - usually when I add information to an array, I make do with a single $push, until I encountered it - an **empty array**.

For some reason I don't understand, neither $push nor $set works with my empty array, and I can't even add rows...

Code:

```py
    if len(row['fractions']) == 0:

        collection.update_one({'_id:': member.id}, {"$set": {"fractions": []}})
        collection.update_one({'_id:': member.id}, {"$push": {"fractions": faction['_id']}})
```

[Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTP3H.png)

At the very least, I have experimented with different types of operators to add data, but have not come up with a solution

Comment: As you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hCr-EA07kD-), `$push` works for all cases: array with data, empty array, no array. It won't work if `fractions`'s type is defined as something which is not array

Comment: @nimrod-serok but.. its empty array, not null

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  If the document in the database has a populated array, empty array, or missing fractions field it should work fine, see https://mongoplayground.net/p/54UrukVrJN-